# How to mint NFT in bulk?

Tags: nft, mint, opensea

If you have around a 1000 NFTs and want to list all those on opensea do you have to pay gas
fee for every single one of those to be listed ?
Or is it more like that you "upload" you NFT work in opensea but not minted yet, but when a buyer
decides to buy one then the buyer mints it and pays the gas fees, and then the ethereum should come to your wallet, it this the case ? Or are there any fees that I have to pay for every NFTs that gets sold ?

Also if you decide to upload your work in bulk do you pay gas price for the whole bulk in opensea ?